# CentOS 7 OpenGL not using Nvidia after install and nvidia-settings fails. Is there a way to force nvidia to be used for everything?

Tags: centos, drivers, nvidia, display, opengl

Good afternoon,

Fresh CentOS 7 server. Installed nvidia drivers (yes for compatibility libraries as well) and able to log into the system. OpenGL still apears to be using the integrated graphics and nvidia-setting does not open to allow me to troubleshoot further.

nvidia-smi leads me to believe the drivers are loaded/working although it seems part of the system is using integrated while nvidia is being used just for 3d rendering.

I would be fine getting it to work entirely with just the nvidia card if possible but the OpenGL is my main concern. Not understanding why nvidia-setting is failing to open unless its a result of the integrated graphics controlling the display? If so how do I change this to allow nvidia to control everything to include the opengl component?

So far I have completely reinstalled the nvidia drivers and reviewed logs/forums extensively trying to see someone similar with this issue.

General info below

```
# nvidia-smi 
Wed Jan 27 16:08:26 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P1000        Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   37C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  4042MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

# nvidia-settings 
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system

# lshw -class display
*-display                 
   description: 3D controller
   product: GP107GLM [Quadro P1000 Mobile]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:515 memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:148 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64)

# glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had to perform the following to get NVIDIA to work correctly on a hybrid graphics laptop. (below expects nouveau to be disabled and nvidia installed already)

Create /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-prime.conf

```
Section "OutputClass"  
  Identifier "nvidia"
  MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
  Driver "nvidia"
  Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
  Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"
EndSection
```

Created two "optimus.desktop" files in /etc/xdg/autostart/ and /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart/ that contains:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Optimus
Exec=sh -c "xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0; xrandr --auto"
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=DisplayServer
```

Add kernel parameter of nvidia-drm.modeset=1 to the end of CRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX inside of /etc/default/grub and run:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg
```

Create /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf using the following:

```
echo "options nvidia_drm modeset=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf
```

Create /etc/dracut.conf.d/nvidia.conf with the following content:

```
add_drivers+=" nvidia nvidia_modeset nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm "
install_items+=" /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf "
```

Run the following command:

```
dracut -f
init6
```

From there NVIDIA was the default graphics and worked as expected.